# Custom Permalinks for Posts only

Tags: permalinks

I'm using a page as my blog archive, ie http://mysite.com/blog 
I'd like to list the posts under that url: http://mysite.com/blog/untitled/hello-world/
I've added Category base "blog" and now my categories appear correctly (http://mysite.com/blog/untitled/), but posts do not.

The thing is that I have other custom post types and I don't want the /blog/ part to appear there too.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is interested:

1. Removed Category base "blog" since it was conflicting with the actual "Blog" page slug.
2. Changed the permalinks to `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`